# Call a service in route module angular 4

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, user-roles, role-based-access-control

```
import {
    RoleGuard
} from '../guards/role-guard.service';

// [...]

children: 
{
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [RoleGuard],
    **
    data: {
        role: 'Admin'
    } **
},
```

I don't want to hard-code role string,i want to fetch roles from role service then pass dynamically routes in Route Module.

Is there any way to call service in routing Module.

Comment: You can use `resolve` for the same

Comment: but using resolve, i would get data in component,i want to pass some dynamically  data in RoleGuard

Comment: Inside the RoleGaurd, you can inject the service, get the data dynamically

Comment: If i add an new role in my application,then i have to write code for new role everytime.